# Adding value to TextBox inside Datalist ItemTemplate

Tags: asp.net

I am creating an application, in which I am displaying the images(contained in a folder) in a datalist. Each datalist cell is having a ImageButton(clicking on which will show large pic of the image), a delete button(clicking which will delete the image), a edit button and a textbox. Clicking on the edit button will cause the imagefile name to get displayed in the textbox.

here is my .aspx code

```html
     <asp:DataList ID="dtlist" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" CellPadding="5" EnableViewState="True">
      <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton Width="100" ID="ImagePic" ImageUrl='<%# Container.DataItem %>' CommandName='<%# Container.DataItem %>' runat="server" OnClick="ImagePic_Click" ImageAlign="Top">
            </asp:ImageButton>
      <br />
            <asp:Button Width="100" ID="btn_image_del" CommandName='<%# Container.DataItem %>' runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="btn_image_del_Click">    
            </asp:Button>
      <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_image_name" Width="100" runat="server" Visible="True" Text='<%# Container.DataItem %>' MaxLength="500" />
            </asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button Width="100" ID="btn_image_edit" CommandName='<%# Container.DataItem %>' runat="server" Text="Edit" OnClick="btn_image_edit_Click">
            </asp:Button>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <ItemStyle BorderColor="Brown" BorderStyle="dotted" BorderWidth="3px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
    </asp:DataList>
```

And the .cs code is as follows

```cs
  protected void BindDataList()//shows the pics from the user folder
    {
            string[] list = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("/Candidate_Pics/" + Convert.ToString(Session["Sex"]) + "/" + txt_u_name.Text + "/"));
            var aList = from fileName in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("/Candidate_Pics/" + Convert.ToString(Session["Sex"]) + "/" + txt_u_name.Text + "/"))
                        select string.Format("/Candidate_Pics/" + Convert.ToString(Session["Sex"]) + "/" + txt_u_name.Text + "/{0}", Path.GetFileName(fileName));
            dtlist.DataSource = aList;
            dtlist.DataBind();
    }

  protected void ImagePic_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        string strImage = ((ImageButton)sender).CommandName;
        ViewState["InsertedURL"] = strImage;
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "ShowValidation", "javascript:ShowPic();", true);
        Large_Pic.ImageUrl = strImage;
    }

  protected void btn_image_del_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string del_selected_image = ((Button)sender).CommandName;
        File.Delete(Server.MapPath(del_selected_image));
    }

  protected void btn_image_edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string edit_selected_image = Path.GetFileName(((Button)sender).CommandName);
        // Now what should i do:
    }
```

The above three function namely ImagePic_Click,btn_image_del_Click, btn_image_edit_Click are working fine..Deletion, then LargePic view are all working perfectly, my problem is that, I want that when the edit button will be clicked, the corresponding name of the image will be displayed in the Datalist textbox. In the just above function, edit_selected_image is holding the filename of the corresponding image. I have tested it by applying breakpoints. Now the problem is that I want this value should be passed to the textbox "txt_image_name" in the Datalist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
TextBox txt =(TextBox)dtlist.FindControl("txt_image_name");
txt.Text = edit_selected_image;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use EditItemTemplate, for editing [Edit Template.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/90xwe9s3.aspx) 
you can write your mark up some tihing like this .

```
<EditItemTemplate>

            PictureName:<asp:Label id="PicutreLabel" 
Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "yourFIleNamePath") %>' runat="server"/> <br />
<asp:LinkButton id="UpdateButton" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" runat="server"/>

<asp:LinkButton id="DeleteButton" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" runat="server"/>

<asp:LinkButton id="CancelButton" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Please read my total post....When u answered me, i was editing my post..Please help me buddy